# How to write "$X$ is the set of all positive integers greater than or equal to $10$" with mathematical notations?

Tags: notation

> How to write "$X$ is the set of all positive integers greater than or equal to $10$" with mathematical notations?

I was thinking $X=\{n:n\ge10\in\mathbb Z^+\}$, but I'm not too sure if this is correct. What is the right way of writing this?

I also remember a notation like $\mathbb Z_{\ge10}$ but I'm not sure if that's right either.

Comment: I would write this as $X=\{n\in\mathbb Z_{++}\,|\,n\geq10\}$. I write $\mathbb Z_{++}$ instead of $\mathbb Z_+$ to emphasize that $0$ is excluded from the definition of “positive integers.”

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
X &= \{n : \textrm{$n$ is a positive integer greater than or equal to $10$}\} \tag{1}  \\
&= \{n : n \in \mathbb Z^+ \textrm{ and } n \geq 10\}  \tag{2} \\
&= \{n \in \mathbb Z^+ : n \geq 10\} \tag{3} \\
&= \{10,11,12,\dots\} \tag{4}
\end{align}

$(1):$ Yes, you can use words.
$(2):$ This is the most correct. 
$(3):$ The standard notation for the latter. 
$(4):$ This is well understood, although it is a bit vague.

Comment: Wait is it $X=\{n\in\mathbb Z^+:n\ge10\}$ or $\{n\in\mathbb Z^+|n\ge10\}$? or does it not matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I like to use dots instead of a bar.